Does 誰と mean 誰とも?
There is one sentence I am confused with in the below panel:


だから気に入らない、誰とつるむでもなく孤高を気取って表面上明るく接して上手くやれてると思ってるアイツが

I am bit confused about the use of 誰と. I think it is supposed to be 誰とも. Is it a typo? Perhaps not because も is placed in でもなく. If that's case then, 誰とつるむでもなく means something like "not hanging out with anyone but..."?
Also, I am not sure whether 誰とも also modifies verbs 気取って, 接して and やれてる, not just つるむ.

It's not a typo. This 誰と～する(わけ)でもない is a variant of the 誰とも～しない construction, with an added nuance of "(not) particularly". It's faster to learn from examples:

どこにも行かない
to go nowhere
どこに行くでもない
not to go anywhere in particular
何もしない
to do nothing
何をするでもない
to do nothing in particular; aimless
何にもならない
to amount to nothing; meaningless
何になるでもない
to amount to nothing in particular; not very meaningful
誰もいない部屋
an empty room
誰がいるでもない部屋(から物音がする)
(There's a sound from) a room where there is no one in particular
誰ともつるまず
hanging out with no one
誰とつるむ(わけ)でもなく
not hanging out with anyone in particular

A similar pattern is explained in this answer. In this construction, か is optional for some reason. For example, どこに行くでもない is the same as どこかに行く(わけ)でもない, but I feel the former feels slightly literary or sophisticated.
誰ともつるむでもなく (with two も) is perfectly understandable, too, but I feel it's a little redundant and awkward.

Yes, and 誰と only modifies つるむ

Also, does 気に入らない modify 誰?

@Axe you can understand the sentence in question as だから誰とつるむでもなく孤高を気取って表面上明るく接して「上手くやれてる」と思ってるアイツが気に入らない. I am bit uncertain whether 上手くやれてる is the only quoted text though.

Thanks, that makes sense

@JohnDavies Yes only "上手くやれてる" is the content of 思ってる.

@user1602 I'm sorry, but I cannot accept "no matter where to go" as a translation of どこへ行くでもなく. They are typically used like "どこへも行かず家でゲームをしている" and "どこへ行くでもなく渋谷をうろうろしている".

BTW one thing I find interesting about this construction is that in the (question word)も version, the question word loses its accent, but in the (question word)するでもない it retains the accent, even though semantically it’s getting affected by the でも in the same way. Normally accents are more bound to semantics but here it seems more bound to syntax.

broccoli forrest identifies a similar accent phenomenon in this answer but there notes that it is more a distance/pragmatic concern due to being blurry. I feel like in the sentences in this answer, saying any of the でもない sentences unaccented would be a little marked, so I feel it’s more clear cut that the copula is syntactically interrupting some accent change. So interesting…

@DariusJahandarie Another interesting feature about accent is that, contrary to the semantic scope, the でもない construction requires accent phrases divided between question word and verb: どこに | 行くでもない, 何を | するでもない etc. I don't know how come it happens, though...

@naruto at least remove "to" from "not going to anywhere in particular", plus be consistent with the verb forms. Dictionary firms should be translated as infinitives, not gerunds (which is a noun expression)

The other answer gives examples which use でもない. I have some examples that seem relevant, but which stray from that pattern. I don't know what to call these sentences, but I want to call them "delayed-も" sentences.
〜こともできない is a pattern:

どうすることもできない
can't do anything
しかし、誰の助けを借りることもできない [narou]
can't get anyone's help
その顔からは何の感情を窺うこともできない [narou]
can't see any expression

Miscellaneous:

何をやったとしても不思議じゃない [danganronpa]
it wouldn't be strange no matter what was done (nothing would surprise me)
どの引き出しに入っているのも、仕事の資料ばかり [danganronpa]
what was in each and every drawer was just documents
毎夜三更を過ぎる頃、紀昌の家の屋上で何者の立てるとも知れぬ弓弦の音がする [名人伝]
a sound not known to be caused by anything in particular (a sound of unknown origin)

I have some thoughts, but I'm not really sure how to explain these. I can't see a straightforward way to reword most of these.
There's a familiar grammar pattern, 〜ても used with a question word, which could be categorized with these delayed-も sentences.
By the way, the panel you posted has another interesting phrase, どんなに面倒臭いおじさんとの飲み会も.
